# Offline bundle works slow

Tags: android, react-native

I have two systems:
On `System 1:` running below command in react-native project directory gives

```
react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

`OUTPUT 1:`

```
[02/09/2017, 19:34:32] <START> Initializing Packager
[02/09/2017, 19:35:22] <START> Building Haste Map
[02/09/2017, 19:35:22] <END>   Building Haste Map (233ms)
[02/09/2017, 19:35:22] <END>   Initializing Packager (50091ms)
[02/09/2017, 19:35:22] <START> Transforming files
[02/09/2017, 19:35:24] <END>   Transforming files (1893ms)
bundle: start
bundle: finish
bundle: Writing bundle output to: android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bund
le
bundle: Copying 5 asset files
bundle: Done writing bundle output
bundle: Done copying assets
```

The command executes in 1 to 2 minutes on average.

On `System 2:` running the same command produces same output only the first time after starting/restarting the system.Later the command executes quickly within 15 to 20 seconds and output is

`OUTPUT 2:`

```
Loading dependency graph, done.
bundle: start
bundle: finish
bundle: Writing bundle output to: android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle
bundle: Copying 5 asset files
bundle: Done writing bundle output
bundle: Done copying assets
```

On `System 1` always `Output 1` is displayed irrespective whenever it is executed. Why `System 2` is optimized after first run.

What changes shall i do on `System 1` to make it faster.

Comment: Can you try bundling with gradle? In your app directory type cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease (production release)

Comment: project directory>`cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease`. It gives '.' is not recognised as an internal or external command. I am running on windows platform

Comment: The issue was solved after re-installing node and react-native with latest version on `System 1`. I didn't found out what was the exact problem. I think there were some version specific issues.